# Keras: Failure to specify steps argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a keras model trained on a `tf.data.Dataset` like this:

```
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
dataset = dataset.batch(50).repeat() 
model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=20)
```

So I preprocess in the same way:

```
x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_test)
x = x.map(lambda x: ({'reviews': x}))
x = x.map(preprocess)
```

and then I do:

```
preds = self.model.predict(x)
```

but unfortunately get back:

```
ValueError: When using iterators as input to a model, you should specify the `steps` argument.
```

Adding in `x = x.batch(50).repeat()` before predicting leads to the same error.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like in your fit method, the steps_per_epoch gives the number of batches that comprise an epoch. Similarly, you would need to specify the number of batches in the test set with steps
So maybe you can batch the test dataset with a batch size of 1 if you want the prediction for each data point, then do something like
model.predict(x.make_one_shot_iterator(), steps=no_of_data_points)?